# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver in eclipse

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

I am also add all jars file of usr/local/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*jars, usr/local/hadoop/common, hive-exec-xxx.jar, hive-metastore-xxx.jar and hive-jdbc-xxx.jar.

hive terminal working well.

My code is:

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

try {
        Class.forName(driverName);
        Connection con;

        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default", "", "");

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

        stmt.executeQuery("CREATE DATABASE demodb");
        System.out.println("Database userdb created successfully.");

        con.close();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at hive.CRUDHive.main(CRUDHive.java:15)
```

Comment: I suggest you either use  Maven/Gradle if you really want to include Hadoop libraries in your projects. Apache Spark would also be easier to integrate into your Hadoop code

Comment: Your driver class it's not in your runtime classpath. It would be better if you could use cricket_007  suggestion.

Comment: I am new in hadoop can you explain how can i check driver class is in right classpath.

Answer (score 5):

Make Sure which jar (hive ) do you want .. because it has diferent versions
The old verison jar is

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

here is the [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop.hive/hive-jdbc)

and the newest jar is `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` [here is the new settings](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hive/hive-jdbc/1.1.0-cdh5.13.1)

check  your  dependency  please

Answer (score 0):

In your code the driver class for hive is mentioned incorrectly. It shoul
d be as below

> private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

If the above change doesn't solve your problem then it means the jar files are not on the classpath which you need to add explicitely.

For the maven based project you can just add the dependency for hive-jdbc jar.

If you are not using maven then in eclipse do the following steps:

> Select Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries ->
>   Add external Jars -> Select path of hive-jdbc/hive-exec/hive-service jars

Along with hive jars you will need to add other dependent jars as a http-core, http-client, hadoop-common, commons-logging, slf4j jars.

Comment: after changing "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" to "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" showing error "No suitable driver found for jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default".

Comment: Have you added the dependency jars to the class path?

Comment: Also while forming connection string you ned to use "jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>/<db>"

Comment: @PraveenParihar use `jdbc:hive2://`